# Python Get text between keywords

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get the text between certain keywords [en] and [ja]

So for the following example:

```
[en]
Text
- Example
- Example
- Example

[ja]
Text
 - 例
 - 例
 - 例
```

I need it to return only:

```
Text
- Example
- Example
- Example
```

I have tried using regex:

```
([en])(.|\n)+?([ja])
```

But it only grabs the first 2 characters of first line. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @anubhava but it also gets [en] and [ja] with it

Comment: Ok then `\[en]\n((?:.*\n)+?)\[ja]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captures all the text between [en] and [ja]

```
(?<=\[en\]\n)(?:(?:.*\n)+?)(?=\n\[ja\])
```

[Regex working link](https://regex101.com/r/oqUsD5/1)

Comment: Is there a way to skip the last line break?

Comment: yes you can use: (?<=\[en\]\n)(?:(?:.*\n)+?)(?=\n\[ja\])

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: ``(?<=\[en]\n)(?:(?:.*\n)+?)(?=\n\[ja\])`` does it

Comment: link and code edited on top. It is working.

Comment: This might get slower in a larger text. Even in demo this is taking many more steps that [capture group solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72885608/548225)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex for capturing text between `[en]` and `[ja]`:

```py
\[en]\n((?:.*\n)*?)\n\[ja]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r85N1Z/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\[en]\n`: Match `[en]` followed by a line break
- `((?:.*\n)+?)`: Match anything followed by a line break. Repeat this group 1+ times (lazy matching) and capture matched text in group #1
- `\n\[ja]`: Match line break followed by `[ja]`

Comment: Is there a way to skip the last line break?

Comment: @HeelMega: Try my updated answer now